# How to get comments data from instagram api

Tags: instagram-api

I have tried to get the Instagram media comments using API. I am getting empty array when I use API .I have tried sandbox live and also I make my profile public but still I get the comment data empty.

```
   instagram.get('/media/2128588978223438874_685479/comments').then(data=> {
    console.log(data); })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);

        })



I expected the output was : {
    "data": [
        {
            "created_time": "1280780324",
            "text": "Really amazing photo!",
            "from": {
                "username": "snoopdogg",
                "profile_picture": "http://images.instagram.com/profiles/profile_16_75sq_1305612434.jpg",
                "id": "1574083",
                "full_name": "Snoop Dogg"
            },
            "id": "420"
        },
        ...
    ] } .
```

but actual output I get was

```
{ data: [], meta: { code: 200 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

`media-id` is just a placeholder for the real Id. Replace it and it will work.
[Here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self) is a request for getting media information, together with it's id.

```
instagram.get('/media/' + media_id + '/comments')
         .then(data => {
            console.log(data); 
         })
         .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
         })
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay Sir. I have tried with real id but still its getting same response { data: [], meta: { code: 200 } }.